# How to prevent an assembly from loading when not used

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-assembly

I am working in Winforms, C# .NET4.5

I have a class in assembly A called classA, which provides method1

In my main assembly I can call this method, but in some cases I am 100% sure that
this can not happen because of some internal flag from a registry key:

```
if( valueFromRegistryIsAlwaysFalse)
{
   var A = new classA();
   A.method1();
}
```

When I set this value in the registry I do not want to provide assembly A with the main executable, however even when I do not use the method it needs assembly A to start. Of course I get this, however is there some way of getting around this?

Comment: Just to clarify; you have an assembly that might be there or not, and a registry setting that should indicate if you need to use classes from it or not, but you want to allow the application to run without trying to load that assembly if the class(es) in it are not needed?

Comment: Strange...IME JIT doesn't load the assembly until the code requires something from the assembly.  You are saying that's not happening.  Have you tested to verify the assembly is loading even when no code is being used?  Have you also verified no other code requires assembly A before this?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey it needs the assembly to JIT the method; avoiding this is usually a pretty simple refactor

Comment: Well our application comes in two version: one that is controlling hardware, two that is doing everything but the hardware. The assembly where all hardware is controlled is used all throughout the main application and it is a huge job to refactor this (I will not be allowed to do that).... I tested this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally, assembly load and fusion happens on-demand when the CLI is JITting any containing method that uses types from an assembly that hasn't been loaded yet. So: the way to "fix" this is to move ALL of the code involving types in this assembly into methods that will never be executed. For example:

```
if( valueFromRegistryIsAlwaysFalse)
{
   DoStuff();
}

[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
void DoStuff()
{
   var A = new classA();
   A.method1();
}
```

With this change, the original method doesn't mention `classA`, so that method can be JITted without needing the extra assembly; and because `DoStuff` is never executed / JITted, it never loads from there either.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for! Is this documented behavior, that will also work for future .NET frameworks? Or am I asking too much now?

Comment: @Enrico it is impossible for me to comment on what does / doesn't work in future .NET frameworks - I lost my crystal ball in my last house move.

Comment: I knew I asked too much, but I could try!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface assembly that both the caller, and classA reference.
Remove the reference and dynamically load the assembly and instantiate the class.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\classAAssembly.dll");
Type type = asm.GetType("classA");
IClassA a = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IClassA;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think for your particular case you can also use MEF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

Comment: Adding reference to another library to prevent loading first one? :)

Comment: :) right. maybe not the best approach, but an approach that let you not include the reference to the main project at all

Answer (score 1):

Normally the framework loads the assemblies on-demand. A different approach would be to use a dynamic load pattern or composite pattern. Starting from the framework 4.0, MS introduced the [System.Addin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace to help programmers in this. I have the following class which I use in my projects to achieve the same with Framework 2.0 compatibility:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [Serializable]
    public enum CompositeLoaderFilter
    {
        ImplementsInterface = 0,
        InheritsBaseClass = 1
    }

    [Serializable]
    public static class Composite
    {
        private static readonly CompositeManager manager = new CompositeManager();

        public static CompositeManager Manager { get { return manager; } }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class CompositeManager : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        private SortedList<string, Type> m_addIns;

        public int GetInMemoryComponents(Type addInType, CompositeLoaderFilter filter)
        {
            m_addIns = internal_GetInMemoryServices(addInType, filter);
            return m_addIns.Count;
        }

        public int GetComponents(Type addInType, CompositeLoaderFilter filter)
        {
            string addInPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            return GetComponents(addInPath, "*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, addInType, filter);
        }

        public int GetComponents(string addInSearchPattern, Type addInType, CompositeLoaderFilter filter)
        {
            string addInPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            return GetComponents(addInPath, addInSearchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, addInType, filter);
        }

        public int GetComponents(string addInPath, string addInSearchPattern, Type addInType, CompositeLoaderFilter filter)
        {
            return GetComponents(addInPath, addInSearchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, addInType, filter);
        }

        public int GetComponents(string addInPath, string addInSearchPattern, SearchOption addInSearchOption, Type addInType, CompositeLoaderFilter filter)
        {
            AppDomainSetup setup = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation;
            setup.PrivateBinPath = addInPath;
            setup.ShadowCopyFiles = "false";

            AppDomain m_appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyNamespace.CompositeManager", null, setup);
            CompositeManager m_remoteLoader = (CompositeManager)m_appDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "MyAssembly.dll"), "MyNamespace.CompositeManager");
            m_addIns = m_remoteLoader.RemoteGetServices(addInPath, addInSearchPattern, addInSearchOption, addInType, filter);

    #if DEBUG
            DebugLoadedAssemblies();
    #endif

            AppDomain.Unload(m_appDomain);
            return m_addIns.Count;
        }

        public object CreateInstance(string typeName)
        {
            if (!m_addIns.ContainsKey(typeName))
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Type {0} was not loaded..", typeName), "typeName");

            MethodInfo method = m_addIns[typeName].GetMethod("GetInstance", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
            if (method != null)
                return method.Invoke(m_addIns[typeName], null);
            else return Activator.CreateInstance(m_addIns[typeName]);
        }

        public object CreateInstance(Type type)
        {
            if (type == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("type", "Type is null");

            if (!m_addIns.ContainsKey(type.FullName))
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Type {0} was not loaded..", type.FullName), "type");

            MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("GetInstance", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
            if (method != null)
                return method.Invoke(type, null);
            else return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }

        public T CreateInstance<T>()
        {
            if (!m_addIns.ContainsKey(typeof(T).FullName))
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Type {0} was not loaded..", typeof(T).FullName), "T");

            MethodInfo method = typeof(T).GetMethod("GetInstance", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
            if (method != null)
                return (T)method.Invoke(typeof(T), null);
            else return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Type> AvailableServices
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Type> item in m_addIns)
                {
                    yield return item.Value;
                }
            }
        }

        public Type[] AvailableTypes
        {
            get
            {
                List<Type> list = new List<Type>();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Type> item in m_addIns)
                    list.Add(item.Value);
                return list.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public T[] GetObjects<T>()
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Type> item in m_addIns)
                list.Add((T)CreateInstance(item.Value));
            return list.ToArray();
        }

        public object[] AvailableObjects
        {
            get
            {
                List<object> list = new List<object>();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Type> item in m_addIns)
                    list.Add(CreateInstance(item.Value));
                return list.ToArray();
            }
        }

        internal SortedList<string, Type> internal_GetInMemoryServices(Type addInType, CompositeLoaderFilter filter)
        {
            SortedList<string, Type> validAddIns = new SortedList<string, Type>();
            Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
            foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
            {
                try
                {
                    Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
                    foreach (Type type in types)
                    {
                        switch (filter)
                        {
                            case CompositeLoaderFilter.ImplementsInterface:
                            if (type.GetInterface(addInType.Name) != null)
                                validAddIns.Add(type.FullName, type);
                            break;

                            case CompositeLoaderFilter.InheritsBaseClass:
                            if (type.BaseType == addInType)
                                validAddIns.Add(type.FullName, type);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (FileLoadException flex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0} MyNamespace.CompositeManager: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), flex.Message));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0} MyNamespace.CompositeManager: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), ex.Message));
                }
            }
            return validAddIns;
        }

        internal SortedList<string, Type> RemoteGetServices(string addInPath, string addInSearchPattern, SearchOption addInSearchOption, Type addInType, CompositeLoaderFilter filter)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(addInPath, addInSearchPattern, addInSearchOption);
            SortedList<string, Type> validAddIns = new SortedList<string, Type>();

            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    if (String.CompareOrdinal(addInPath, file) != 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
                            Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
                            foreach (Type type in types)
                            {
                                switch (filter)
                                {
                                    case CompositeLoaderFilter.ImplementsInterface:
                                    if (type.GetInterface(addInType.Name) != null)
                                        validAddIns.Add(type.FullName, type);
                                    break;

                                    case CompositeLoaderFilter.InheritsBaseClass:
                                    if (type.BaseType == addInType)
                                        validAddIns.Add(type.FullName, type);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (FileLoadException flex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0} MyNamespace.CompositeManager: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), flex.Message));
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0} MyNamespace.CompositeManager: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), ex.Message));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    #if DEBUG
            DebugLoadedAssemblies();
    #endif

            return validAddIns;
        }

    #if DEBUG
        internal void DebugLoadedAssemblies()
        {
            foreach (Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                //Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Domain: {0} Assembly: {1}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, a.FullName));
            }
        }
    #endif
    }
}
```

Following a sample usage:

```
Composite.Manager.GetComponents(typeof(IMyService), CompositeLoaderFilter.ImplementsInterface);
IMyService[] services = Composite.Manager.GetObjects<IMyService>();
```

The class will load all the assemblies in current folder, inspecting them to see if they contains a Type that match the input parameters. Because is impossible to unload an assembly once loaded, the class will load them inside a different AppDomain, which in contrary to single assemblies, can be dropped.

In order to use it in your project you should proceed as following:

- Remove the (hard) reference to your assembly
- Implement an interface to communicate with your class
- Load the types that implements the above interface
- Use your class through the interface

Hope it helps :)